# Firebase Cloud messaging : app/invalid-credential - failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been facing the same issue randomly i.e. this issue occurs sometime while working fine most of the time. Running nodejs version 14.x over AWS Lambda.

```
Error sending message: FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: connect ETIMEDOUT ".
    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:85:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async fetchVideosAndUsers (/var/task/src/videos-notifications.js:180:17)
    at async doAction (/var/task/src/videos-notifications.js:233:30)
    at async Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/src/) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/invalid-credential',
    message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: connect ETIMEDOUT".'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app'
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be caused by an issue with your application’s credentials. You can try checking the following:

- Ensure that you’re requesting the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging, as you’ll need this to authorize access to FCM for your app.
- Ensure that you [obtain the proper service account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk). Then generate a private key file(in JSON format) to authorize access to Firebase services.